# Solving nonlinear second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation
$$
y''=\tan^{2}\left(x+y'+\frac{\pi}{2}\right), \hspace{10mm}y(0)=1, \hspace{2mm}y'(0)=0
$$
I reduced it to:
$$
2y'-\sin\left(2x+2y'\right)=2x
$$
But a I don't know how to get $y$. I have tried but I can't find the way.

Comment: I realized that, but I received the problem with those initial conditions. Anyway I need to solve the problem, at least without initial conditions.

Comment: I would be very surprised even by an analytical solution for $y'$.